# 'git pull' reverts changes made by others

Tags: git, commit

I am using a git repository with other people to work on a document. When I pull, the changes made by others are reverted, and this reversion is considered as a change that I made. Of course, if I commit it and push it, I propagate this bad version to the repo.

This is not the first time I am working with other people through git, but this is the first time this happens to me. And it happens almost every time I pull.

I really don't understand how it is possible.

Thank you

EDIT:
Output of `git config -l`:

```
user.email=***
user.name=***
push.default=matching
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=***.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.name1.remote=origin
branch.name1.merge=refs/heads/name1
branch.name2.remote=origin
branch.name2.merge=refs/heads/name2
```

EDIT 2:

I made this experiment:

```
git pull
git commit -a -m "bad version"
git checkout (hash of penultimate commit)
```

I obtain the version I am looking for (the last version published by the others). But it is unusable, as the HEAD is detached.

EDIT 3:

OK. I think there is a conflict between git and TeXmaker. After `git pull`, I have unstaged changes (the files which should have been modified stay as they are). When I run `git reset --hard` if the document is used by TeXmaker, it does nothing, and if TeXmaker is closed, `git reset --hard` works (the document returns to its state in the last commit).

Comment: Are you all working on the same branch? And are you getting any conflicts when you pull?

Comment: I find it helps to *avoid* `git pull`. The pull command is meant as a convenience short-cut—it runs `git fetch`, then it runs a second Git command. It's the second command that usually goes wrong. Run each of the two commands and see if each one works, and if the second one goes wrong, ask specifically about (or search for StackOverflow posts for) the second one. Now: which second command are you telling `git pull` to run: `git merge`, or `git rebase`?

Comment: Can you add the output of `git config -l` (after censoring sensible information) and the name of the branch you're working on?

Comment: It happens when changes are made on 'master' and I pull 'master'. There are no conflicts when I pull.

Comment: Are you and your colleague not only working on a same repository but also on the same DIRECTORY on a given server or workstation ? I've already seen that before…

Comment: We are not working on the same directory.

Comment: A detached head isn’t unusable. Just create a branch there.

Comment: Thanks. These settings look pretty normal, except maybe `push.default=matching
`, since `simple` is usually the default for that setting nowadays. Can you explain exactly how exactly do you trigger the issue? E.g. what does `status` say after the `pull`? If you only see it during a `push` it might well be that some of your other branches have unpushed conflicting changes. You can try an explicit `git push origin master:master` to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this behavior is due to an unexpected interaction between git and TeXmaker, the software I use to edit the document. If the document is open in TeXmaker, `git pull` does not change the document, then causes the problem I described.

The solution could be: close TeXmaker, then pull and reopen TeXmaker. Or use another software, I think.

Comment: It's probably the case that Git *does* change the file, but TeXmaker believes that TeXmaker is in charge of the file, and ... *changes it back*.

Comment: This can happen with many different editors I think. If you have a file open in an editor, then do git pull, causing git to update the file on the file system, the cached version you have open in your editor may be outdated. This happens to me if I use `vim` also. But `vim` gives a warning when I try to save the file in this case, saying `WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!`.